# In Freemarker, How to check what value is assigned to a variable ? for eg. in Javascript we have "console.log(x)" lets us know x value

Tags: freemarker

I want to check value of an object variable used in my freemarker template. Is there any way of checking similar to console.log of Javascript (or any equivalent method) ?

Comment: Not possible. FreeMarker runs on the server side, JavaScript on the client side.

Comment: Freemarker is used to apply some data to template so is not printing it in template the checking you want?